# How do I maintain my menu, and footer in the same place while horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, positioning

*edit/update*

I have updated my code and fixed some errors. Now I am trying to fix my footer to stay at the bottom, my menu will not center, and I am trying to have the gallery between header and footer without being clipped by the header. Everything was working until I added the horizontal scroll gallery.

I am trying to achieve the layout:

- header top
- menu in a line
- content/horizontal scroll gallery middle
- footer/social icons bottom

Please help

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/nerd1992/pen/KZmjJm)

```css
/**********************************
General
**********************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  }

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

/**********************************
Heading
**********************************/
header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 position:fixed;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/**********************************
Navigatoin
**********************************/

nav {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 20px 0 0;
 position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
 }

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

/**********************************
Body
**********************************/

#content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  top: 0;
 
}

/**********************************
Footer
**********************************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
 position: fixed;
 
}

.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.fttext {
 
 text-align: center;
}

/**********************************
Colors
**********************************/


/* site body */
body {
  background-color: #C9BD7C;
  color: #5B0123;
}

/* green header */
header{
  background: #5B0123;
  border-color: #5B0123;
}

/* nav background on mobile devices */
nav {
 background: #B41C42;
}

/* logo text */
h1, h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: #C86347;

}

/* nav link */
nav a, nav a:visited {
 color: #fff;
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color: #F8D295;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa|Passion+One|Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<!-- content goes here-->
<body>
 <header>
       <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <h1>Natalie Davis</h1>
        <h2>Designer</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <section id="content">
   <div id="img-container">
          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 573px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 543px;">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg" width="543" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning">
                <div class="title"><a href="link">link</a> - Test caption and link</div>
                <div class="caption">stuff </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 1124px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 1094px;">
              <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54630/japanese-cherry-trees-flowers-spring-japanese-flowering-cherry-54630.jpeg" width="1094" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning">
                <div class="caption"><i>CAPTION</i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 382px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 352px;">
              <img src="http://www.tonyandsonsnurseries.com.au/images/Plants/Frangipani/FruitSaladLarge.jpg" width="352" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning">
                <div class="caption"><i>CAPTION</i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 439px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 409px;">
              <img src="http://www.beautifulflowerpictures.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/beauty_berry_issai_31.jpg" width="409" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 752px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 722px;">
              <img src="https://freedfromtime.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/farmopolis-flowers-dsc_6487.jpg?w=722&h=600" width="722" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 1094px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 1064px;">
              <img src="https://www.openfootage.net/Openfootage/Vorschau/00299_GelbeBluete/00299_GelbeBluete_Preview_v01.jpg" width="1064" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning">
                <div class="caption"><i>CAPTION</i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 1525px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 1495px;">
              <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/09a7b6_b09cf68226774f6d8af396d240573130.jpg/v1/fill/w_1495,h_600,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/09a7b6_b09cf68226774f6d8af396d240573130.webp" width="1495" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="picture_holder" style="width: 560px;">
            <div class="picture" style="width: 530px;">
              <img src="http://www.besgroup.org/wp-content/uploads/SunbirdBrTh-Costus-JWee-1.jpg" width="530" height="600" alt="">
              <div class="captioning"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- mousewheel java script -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
          function handle(delta) {
            if (delta < 0)
              ScrollSmoothly(10, 10, 'right');
            else if (delta > 0)
              ScrollSmoothly(10, 10, 'left');
            else
            ;
          }

          function wheel(event) {
            var delta = 0;
            if (!event)
              event = window.event;
            if (event.wheelDelta) {
              delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
              if (window.opera)
                delta = -delta;
            } else if (event.detail) {
              delta = -event.detail / 3;
            }
            if (delta)
              handle(delta);
            if (event.preventDefault)
              event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
          }

          var repeatCount = 0;

          function ScrollSmoothly(scrollPos, repeatTimes, direction) {
            if (repeatCount < repeatTimes)
              if (direction == 'right')
                window.scrollBy(20, 0);
              else
                window.scrollBy(-20, 0);
            else {
              repeatCount = 0;
              clearTimeout(cTimeout);
              return;
            }
            repeatCount++;
            cTimeout = setTimeout("ScrollSmoothly('" + scrollPos + "','" + repeatTimes + "','" + direction + "')", 10);
          }

          /* Initialization code. */
          if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
          window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

        </script>
       
        <style type="text/css">
          #img-container {
            width: 6450px;
          }
          
          #img-container #text {
            float: left;
            width: 675px;
          }
          
          #img-container #text p {
            width: 600px;
          }
          
          #img-container .picture_holder {
            float: left;
          }
          
          #img-container .picture {
            /* padding-top: 100px; */
          }
          
          #img-container .captioning .title {
            margin-top: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
          }
          
          #img-container .captioning .caption {}

        </style>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  </section>
 </div>
 
 
 <footer class="fttext">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/NatroseDavis"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/natalierosedavis/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <p>&copy; 2018 Natalie Davis.</p>
 </footer>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/87vwe5ar/)

Comment: thank you for this. I have updated my code and I am still having trouble with my footer not staying at the bottom and centered. And now my menu is not in the center just below my header.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you've posted, in your CSS, your menu styles were targeting an ID, whereas, in your HTML, your menu code had a class instead. Changing the CSS for menu to a class instead of an ID, the styles are then applied, and if the position is changed from absolute to fixed, it then behaves as desired.

```
 .menu {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkred;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I fixed it now.

Comment: I have updated my code and I am still having trouble with my footer not staying at the bottom and centered. And now my menu is not in the center just below my header.